# Chrome's ghost process hogging my internet bandwidth

Tags: mac, google-chrome, bandwidth

In chrome's Task Manager tab, I see that "Browser" task is using up around 100KB/s. Although no other tab is consuming any of the bandwidth. I am eager to find this ghost process hidden in "Browser" that is hogging up the bandwidth and subsequently kill it.

[image]

**EDIT:**
This is how normally Task Manager appears
[image]

Comment: WAY too vague on details.  We can tell from the image this is on mac but what we also need to know is whether that tab is  downloading anything, or  some other form of  push notification / syncing ( i.e. dropbox via the browser) also do you have any odd or  excessive  extensions /  plugins installed that might be hogging bandwidth (easy way to test this is  to launch chrome in safe mode)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I believe that ANY activity (like push notification/dropbox sync etc) spawns an individual process and is duly reported in Task Manager as a separate Task.

Comment: Added another screenshot

Comment: I'd consider looking at the mac performance as a whole those  memory usages look too high for even chrome natively.